# Using Format in a livebindings CustomFormat

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, livebindings

I'm trying to use LiveBindings to format a number for display in a TEdit on a FireMonkey form.

I'm trying to use the Format method in the CustomFormat of the binding to format the number with two decimal places.

I can 'hard code' the output:

```
Format("Hello", %s)
```

which is working, but I can't work out what formatting string to use. If I try a standard formatting string such as,

```
Format("%.2f", %s)
```

I get a runtime error "Format invalid or incompatible with argument".

Indeed I get an error whenever I include a % symbol in the format string, so I'm guessing Format takes a different type of argument, but I can't find any documentation to say what the correct format string is.

Comment: There is documentation for the CustomFormat property in http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Default_LiveBindings_Methods, however, the example they give Format("%d %d", 1, 2) gives the same invalid or incompatible with argument error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameter is passed into CustomFormat as %s. The bindings system preparses out this parameter before the data is passed onto the evaluator. Thus any other % symbols in the CustomFormat string will give an error.

As with a normal format string you can include a literal % sign by putting a double % (i.e. %%).

So, any %s in the format string need to be converted to %%, e.g.

```
Format('%%.2f', %s)
```

which gets parsed out to

```
Format('%.2f', 67.66666)
```

and then parsed down to

```
67.67
```

for display.

If you want to include a literal % in the final output you need to put a quadrupal %, e.g.

```
Format('%%.2f%%%%', %s)
```

becomes

```
Format('%.2f%%', 67.6666)
```

and displays as

```
67.67%
```

Note: The normal format function takes a final parameter which is an array of values. The Format method in the bindings system takes a variable length list of parameters.

Also, the method names are case sensitive. 'Format' is correct, 'format' will fail.

Comment: I can't get your `Format('%%.2f', %s)` Allways `Invalid Argument` . So show how you bind the things together.

Comment: Maybe `Format('%%.2f', Value)` will help you. @moskito-x

Answer (score 3):

You can not use `Format('%.2f',[%s])` in `LiveBindings -> CustomFormat`

**The %s is reserved for the data and for a TEdit , it's a string**

```
d : double;
s : string;
...
d := 1234.5678;
s:=Format('%.2f',[d]);
```

Format() is to convert [int, decimal, double, float] to a **string** .
all other give you a error : `invalid argument`
valid is for example

```
TLinkControlToField1 -> CustomFormat : "Double : "+UpperCase(%s)
```

will give you in Edit1.text

```
Double : 1234.5678
```

OK , we know that Uppercase() for '1234.5678' has no effects .
Is only to show (%s) is a string

**Solutions:**

- Set to TFloatField -> DisplayFormat `#00000.00`
  rounds and display  `01234.57`
- check  TFloatField -> currency
  rounds and display  `1234.57`
- use a component look here
  [LiveBindings in XE3: Formatting your Fields](http://www.malcolmgroves.com/blog/?p=1226)

---

[image]

Comment: Glad you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

imput 67.6666

CUSTOM FORMAT: ToStr(Format('%%.2f', Value)) + ' %%'

output 67.00 %