# FormatFloat in Livebinding

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, livebindings

I'm currently trying to use XE5 livebindings to bind a `TTrackBar.Value` property to a `TLabel.text` property. The TrackBar has a `frequency` of 0.1. Unfortunately, what I'm finding is that with the binding in place, the label is displaying increments that aren't exactly 0.1.

For example, if I set the livebinding links 'CustomFormat' property to `%s+'x'`, the label will sometimes display the extended float value, so instead of say displaying 0.6, it'll display something like 0.6004874613100 which makes the UI look messy.

I am aware of the `FormatFloat` routine, but unfortunately this isn't accepted by the CustomFormat field in the link itself.

Is there any way to format the value so it only displays the short version (i.e. 0.6) instead of the extended value? I know I could manually code it in, but I've got several components in a similar situation and I'd like to use livebindings where possible.

Comment: Won't the use of non-representable floating point values lead to accumulation of rounding errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like Format('%%.1f',%s)
See Mike Sutton's answer here on SO: [Using Format in a livebindings CustomFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801484/using-format-in-a-livebindings-customformat)