# Change the Number Format in TListView TObjectAppearance

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, livebindings, tlistview

I have TListView livebinded with the TFDQuery. One of the data is mapped to `Item Detail` which is basically a number. I would like the number to be formatted to ##,##0.00. Looking at the `Object Inspector` there is no property that I can change the data format.

Is there a way that I can change the ItemAppearance of a number in the TListView?

Below the screenshot showing the `Object Inspector`, `Toogle Design`, and `Debug` views:

[image: screenshot showing the Object Inspector, Toogle Design, and Debug views]

FMX Procedures:

```
unit Unit9;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.ListView.Types, FMX.ListView.Appearances, FMX.ListView.Adapters.Base,
  FireDAC.Stan.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Option, FireDAC.Stan.Error, FireDAC.UI.Intf,
  FireDAC.Phys.Intf, FireDAC.Stan.Def, FireDAC.Stan.Pool, FireDAC.Stan.Async,
  FireDAC.Phys, FireDAC.Phys.SQLite, FireDAC.Phys.SQLiteDef,
  FireDAC.Stan.ExprFuncs, FireDAC.FMXUI.Wait, FireDAC.Stan.Param, FireDAC.DatS,
  FireDAC.DApt.Intf, FireDAC.DApt, Data.Bind.EngExt, Fmx.Bind.DBEngExt,
  System.Rtti, System.Bindings.Outputs, Fmx.Bind.Editors, Data.Bind.Components,
  Data.Bind.DBScope, Data.DB, FireDAC.Comp.DataSet, FireDAC.Comp.Client,
  FMX.ListView, FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit;

type
  TForm9 = class(TForm)
    lbl1: TLabel;
    lsv1: TListView;
    con1: TFDConnection;
    qryLists: TFDQuery;
    bdr1: TBindSourceDB;
    bdl1: TBindingsList;
    tcf1: TLinkFillControlToField;
    lpfText: TLinkPropertyToField;
    qryInsert: TFDQuery;
    btn1: TButton;
    lnkcntrltfld1: TLinkControlToField;
    procedure btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form9: TForm9;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm9.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryInsert.ParamByName('id').AsInteger := 1;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('cur_datetime').AsDateTime := now;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('name').AsString := 'sample';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('size_cont').AsString := 'size_cont';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('qty').AsFloat := 10;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('est_price').AsFloat := 1234.5;
  qryInsert.ParamByName('qty_price').AsString := '10 x 1234.5';
  qryInsert.ParamByName('estimate').AsFloat := 10 * 1234.5;
  qryInsert.ExecSQL;
  qryLists.Close;
  qryLists.Open();
end;

end.
```

FMX File:

```
object Form9: TForm9
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form9'
  ClientHeight = 480
  ClientWidth = 308
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object lbl1: TLabel
    Align = Top
    StyledSettings = [Family, Style, FontColor]
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 33.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TextSettings.Font.Size = 14.000000000000000000
    TextSettings.HorzAlign = Center
    Text = '1869'
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object lsv1: TListView
    ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TImageListItemBottomDetailAppearance'
    ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TImageListItemBottomDetailShowCheckAppearance'
    HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 407.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 1
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Width = 201.000000000000000000
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.Height = 20.000000000000000000
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Text.PlaceOffset.Y = 1.000000000000000000
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Detail.Width = 201.000000000000000000
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Detail.Height = 20.000000000000000000
    ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.Detail.PlaceOffset.Y = 24.000000000000000000
  end
  object btn1: TButton
    Align = Bottom
    Position.Y = 440.000000000000000000
    Size.Width = 308.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 40.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 7
    Text = 'btn1'
    OnClick = btn1Click
  end
  object con1: TFDConnection
    Params.Strings = (
      
        'Database=D:\My Project Files\5. my_projects_aws-rest\project_x_v' +
        '0\application\client\database\smartcart.s3db'
      'LockingMode=Normal'
      'DriverID=SQLite')
    Connected = True
    LoginPrompt = False
    Left = 72
    Top = 24
  end
  object qryLists: TFDQuery
    Active = True
    Connection = con1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'SELECT id, date_created, name, size_cont, qty_price, estimate'
      'FROM lists ORDER BY date_created DESC')
    Left = 112
    Top = 24
  end
  object bdr1: TBindSourceDB
    DataSet = qryLists
    ScopeMappings = <>
    Left = 152
    Top = 24
  end
  object bdl1: TBindingsList
    Methods = <>
    OutputConverters = <>
    Left = 20
    Top = 5
    object tcf1: TLinkFillControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      Control = lsv1
      Track = True
      FillDataSource = bdr1
      AutoFill = True
      FillExpressions = <
        item
          SourceMemberName = 'estimate'
          ControlMemberName = 'Detail'
        end>
      FillHeaderExpressions = <>
      FillBreakGroups = <>
    end
    object lpfText: TLinkPropertyToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdr1
      FieldName = 'estimate'
      Component = lbl1
      ComponentProperty = 'Text'
    end
    object lnkcntrltfld1: TLinkControlToField
      Category = 'Quick Bindings'
      DataSource = bdr1
      FieldName = 'estimate'
      Track = False
    end
  end
  object qryInsert: TFDQuery
    Connection = con1
    SQL.Strings = (
      'INSERT INTO lists (id, date_created, name, size_cont, '
      '                   qty, est_price, qty_price, estimate) '
      'VALUES (:id, :cur_datetime, :name, :size_cont, '
      '        :qty, :est_price, :qty_price, :estimate);')
    Left = 192
    Top = 24
    ParamData = <
      item
        Name = 'ID'
        DataType = ftInteger
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'CUR_DATETIME'
        DataType = ftDateTime
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'NAME'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'SIZE_CONT'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'QTY'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'EST_PRICE'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'QTY_PRICE'
        DataType = ftString
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end
      item
        Name = 'ESTIMATE'
        DataType = ftFloat
        ParamType = ptInput
        Value = Null
      end>
  end
end
```

Comment: In livebindings, there should be a `CustomFormat` property. See [ListView and LiveBindings](https://blog.andreamagni.eu/2018/10/itdevcon-9-listview-and-livebindings/)

Comment: @LURD Thank you for sharing this idea. I am surprised there is such as this CustomFormat property in LiveBindings. Now, I am having difficulty getting the right syntax. This format code ``Format(‘%n’, Owner.estimate.AsFloat + 0.0)`` seems not to me. Still trying to figure out. I am getting an error `invalid or incompatible with argument`.

Comment: See [Using Format in a livebindings CustomFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18801484/576719) for some inputs how to enter expressions in `CustomFormat`. I have never used it (nor FMX) and just skimming the Delphi help did not bring me to a better explanation.

Comment: @LURD Perfect! The second comment works! Thank you so much. Can you put your answer here so I could mark it as answered.

Comment: I would suggest that you put the answer here. Its perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @LURD I will. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 approaches applicable to this case:

1. At TListView level `TLinkControlToField1 -> CustomFormat : "$ "+UpperCase(%s)`. This is the most applicable approach as the number stays in its number format and can be included in the calculation. You might wonder what the `Uppercase` is doing here? It is only to show (%s) the data as string and has no effect.
2. Use the `Display Format` of the TDataset field with this format `$ #,##0.00`. In this approach, the `$` will create an error when you start to include this number in your calculation.

You should check this link to a more detailed explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/18819719/13810710.